# Copy in Postgresql: Absolute Path Interpreted as Relative Path

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running this statement in a Django app:

```
c = connections['default'].cursor()
    query="copy (select * from analysis.\"{0}\") to STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;".format(view_name)
            with open(csvFile,'w') as f:
                c.copy_expert(query,f)
            f.close()
```

It does not create the correct csv file. Some of the values appear to be in the wrong columns. I am trying to test the SQL statement by running it in POSTGRESQL:

```
 copy (select * from analysis."S03_2005_activity_140807_153431_with_geom") to 'C:/djangoProjects/web_output/csvfiles/S03_2005_activity_140807_153431_with_geom.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

It gives me: "ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file". I have looked into the issue and it appears to typically be one of two issues: 1. confusing '\' and '/'. My slashes should be correct. 2. The server being on a different computer. I thought this may be my issue as the database is located on an external computer, but I have the connection in my Postgresql. It also runs from Django so I'm not sure why it isn't working from PG Admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to store data / get data from your local machine and communicate with a Postgres server on a different, remote machine, you cannot simply use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html).

Try the meta-command [**`\copy`** in psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html). It's a wrapper for the SQL `COPY` command and uses local files.

Your ***filename*** should work as is on a Windows machine, but Postgres interprets it as a *local* filename *on the server*, which is probably a Unix derivate. And there the filename would have to start with '/'.

Comment: It's *so* annoying that PgAdmin-III doesn't support psql meta-commands; makes this kind of question much harder to deal with. "Oh, you have to use a different database client just to make this work". Meh. OTOH, that stems from `psql` not being usable as a library, which is a problem in its self.

Comment: The method I am currently using seems to work from my Django app and I get the same result using \copy from psql. My data still doesn't line up in the correct columns. The problem is that one column has blank cells.

Comment: The column data type is geometry.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with excel. The cells contain too many characters. If I open it in notepad++, the values line up in their correct columns. Excel allows 32,767 characters and some of my geometry columns have 35,000+. I believe the statement works in Django, but not Postgresql, because Django is able to connect to a remote Postgresql server in its settings regardless of the host server for Django.